# Condition to check string matches a pattern

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace a string if it matches pattern.
example :`2(M_A)`

```java
String s="2(M_A)";
    if (s.matches([0-9()])) {
        //
    }
```

Comment: I wish you success with that.  Did you have a question for us?

Comment: What are you trying to match and what is the replacement logic?

Comment: To match that pattern, try `[0-9]\\([A-Z]_[A_Z]\\)`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this ;

```
if(s.matches("[0-9]*\\(.*\\)")){
     //do sth 
}
```

- `[0-9]*` matches with first part of string which is `2` in your string.
- `\\(.*\\)` is matching with `"(anything)"`. `\\` is escape character.
  Don't forget to do it. `.*` matches with all chars.

Answer (score 0):

use java regex library.

Referece - [JavaTPoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex)

```
if (Pattern.matches("[0-9]*\\(.*\\)", s)){
   // your code
}
```